# Android ViewPagerIndicator Checkboxes wrong mark

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

i'm working on a small List App which uses ViewPagerIndicator. Each Page uses the same LIstFragment but is filled with different data from database.
Each Listitem contains a checkbox, textview and an ImageButton.

Everything works fine but the checkboxes in the list which are in the memory (0, 1) has different marks. They are blue but the checkboxes on the further lists has green marks.

I thought that a custom checkbox image would fix this but it didn't help.
Now the checkboxes looks like this:

[image]

Maybe someone have a clue and can give me a hint or something where i can read this up.